# Can't Install OCI8 on Ubuntu 23.10 PHP 8.2

Tags: server, apache2, php, oracle

I'm running Apache 2.4 on a Ubuntu 23.10 server with PHP 8.2 and I can't install the OCI8 extension in order to connect to Oracle.

I installed the Oracle instant client 12.2 and php-pear.
When I run:`pecl install oci8`
I get this error: `checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared checking PHP version... configure: error: You need at least PHP 8.1.0 to be able to use this version of OCI8. Use OCI8 2.0 for PHP 5.6.31`

I previously had a PHP 5.6 built from a makefile but I removed it. It seems pecl still believes I'm running PHP 5.6. I created symbolic links from the PHP8.2 to the old PHP, otherwise pear and pecl woudn't start:
`ln -s /usr/bin/php8.2 /usr/bin/php`
Now phpinfo and `php -v` both show PHP8.2 as the version that's running.

I tried to reinstall PHP 8.2 and php-pear, but it says I already have the newest version.
What can I do to be rid of this error and be able to install OCI8?